# MIPS- Program to remove strings with a starting Uppercase

Tags: assembly, mips

I want to write a program that removes any strings that starts with non-lowercase for example "Today is A great Day" would be Today A Day" but I am having a difficult time writing a function that does that so far i have a program that only loads the first character and second character for comparison and loops through the user input without any processing.I do not know how to move from here can't seem to figure out a logical way to go about it

```
.data
input .space 30
prompt: .asciiz "Please enter a sentence "


.text
li $v0,4
li $a0,prompt
syscall
# Read user input
li $v0,8
li $a1,30
la $a0,input
syscall
li $t0,$a0
li $t1,0
loop:
slti $t2,$t1,30
li $t3,1
beq $t2,$t3,EXIT
lb $t4, 0($t0)
lb $t5, 1($t0)
next:
addi $t0,$t0,1
addi $t1,$t1,1
j loop

EXIT:
li $v0,10
syscall
```

Comment: Working out an algorithm in assembly is very hard when first learning assembly.  So, the idea is to make it easier by separating the concerns of working out the algorithm and working out the assembly code for it.  This can be done by working out your algorithm in C or other language first, make sure it works by running it, then translate to assembly code.  This way bugs in the assembly code can only come from relatively minor translation errors and not from algorithmic problems.  And it is so much easier to work out an algorithm in a language you already know.

Comment: Your title and text don't match the example! You remove lowercased words instead.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you're looking for is some kind of [state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine), which can be coded using variables for the states, or even easier instead simply using different sections of code for each state, which might be connected by goto's (very assembly friendly) or maybe if-then-else's.

Beyond the states, you need a pointer variable that refers to your string and advances one character at a time.

The state machine does what you define it to do with the next input character, according to the rules of the current state.  Each state (except terminal states) looks at the one character that is pointed to and advance the pointer, takes some action (like print or copy), and determines the next state, which is maybe the same or maybe a different one.  The next (or same) state runs, again taking the character to determine its actions and the next state.

Certain computing problems lend themselves to state machines, in particular those that require a small history or memory, though do not require dynamically counting things.  (A state machine needs states to count things, and, states are not dynamically added.  So counting in large numbers would require many states.)

### State 1

When you're in state 1, you haven't started a word, so if you see a non-word character (like a space) then you might copy it to the output and stay in state 1.

When you see a valid word character in state 1, it must be the start of a word (or else you'd be in another state), so, if it is upper case, you output it and transition to state 2, but if it was lower case, you don't output it and transition to state 3.

### State 2

When you're in state 2, you've found the start of a word you want to output.  In state 2 it continues to outputting the rest of the word (i.e. take one character, output it, and stay in state 2), until a separator is found, then (output it and) transition back to state 1.

### State 3

When you're in state 3, you've found the start of a word you want to skip.  In state 3, it continues through characters without outputting (staying in state 3) until a separator is found, then transition back to state 1.

### State 4

End state, the state machine is done and the program can move on or quit.  Seeing a terminal (nul character or maybe newline) from any other state should come here.

---

How you handle or collect the output is another matter, you can output one character to the console at a time as you go, or, you can gather the characters you want to keep into another string (another character array), or you can overwrite the existing string, which is possible b/c the problem only shortens the string (doesn't lengthen the string, which would indicate using a 2nd buffer).